# With 'cxf-xjc-plugin' generated classes do not properly import other generated classes

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cxf, maven-plugin

I want to generate Java classes from multiple, on each other dependent, to me provided XSD files.

Because I use Java 11 I try to achieve this with the [cxf-xjc-plugin](https://cxf.apache.org/cxf-xjc-plugin.html) for Maven.

The generating part does work fine for the most part but one:
the import of other generated types

**For example, I have this (generated) class which should import another generated class. It will be generated like this:**

```java
public class FATCAFileErrorNotificationType implements NotificationInterface {
    @XmlElement(name = "FATCANotificationHeaderGrp", namespace = "urn:fatca:fatcanotificationbase", required = true)
    protected FATCANotificationHeaderGrpType fatcaNotificationHeaderGrp;
    @XmlElement(name = "OriginalFileMetadataGrp", namespace = "urn:fatca:fatcanotificationbase", required = true)
    protected OriginalFileMetadataGrpType originalFileMetadataGrp;
    @XmlElement(name = "HCTATreatyStampTxt", namespace = "urn:fatca:fatcanotificationbase")
    protected String hctaTreatyStampTxt;
....
```

The simple data types like `String` or `int` do as I expect but more complex things like the (generated) `FATCANotificationHeaderGrpType` give out an error because [they cannot be imported.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emep4.png)

**If I however add the package name(fatca), like so, it is fine:**

```java
public class FATCAFileErrorNotificationType implements NotificationInterface {
    @XmlElement(name = "FATCANotificationHeaderGrp", namespace = "urn:fatca:fatcanotificationbase", required = true)
    protected fatca.FATCANotificationHeaderGrpType fatcaNotificationHeaderGrp;
    @XmlElement(name = "OriginalFileMetadataGrp", namespace = "urn:fatca:fatcanotificationbase", required = true)
    protected fatca.OriginalFileMetadataGrpType originalFileMetadataGrp;
    @XmlElement(name = "HCTATreatyStampTxt", namespace = "urn:fatca:fatcanotificationbase")
    protected String hctaTreatyStampTxt;
....
```

I've already tried to change the package name or the XSD but both to no avail.

**If it helps this is my config for the plugin**

```xml
          <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
               <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.3.1</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <id>xjc</id>
                       <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
                       </goals>
                       <configuration>
                           <xsdOptions>
                               <xsdOption>
                                   <xsdDir>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd</xsdDir>
                                   <packagename>fatca</packagename>
                                   <extension>true</extension>
                                   <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xjb/bindings.xjb</bindingFile>
                                   <extensionArgs>
                                       <extensionArg>-Xinheritance</extensionArg>
                                   </extensionArgs>
                               </xsdOption>
                           </xsdOptions>
                           <extensions>
                               <extension>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics:1.11.1</extension>
                           </extensions>
                       </configuration>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
```

**I also add an interface to the generated class with this config:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings version="2.1"
               xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:inheritance="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance"
               jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
    <jaxb:bindings
            schemaLocation="../xsd/FATCA-FILE-ERROR-NOTIFICATION-2.5.xsd"
            node="//xs:complexType[@name='FATCAFileErrorNotificationType']">
        <inheritance:implements>NotificationInterface
        </inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings
            schemaLocation="../xsd/FATCA-VALID-FILE-NOTIFICATION-2.5.xsd"
            node="//xs:complexType[@name='FATCAValidFileNotificationType']">
        <inheritance:implements>NotificationInterface
        </inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>

Thanks in advance for any answers
```

Comment: How do you generate and compile the code? Did you check - does it work from command line Maven?

Comment: @Andrey I usually start from the IntelliJ Maven interface. `mvn clean package` from the command line does also not work.